# GAM plots: partial effects, shifted y-axis, or predictions - which representations/interpretations are correct/accurate?

Tags: data-visualization, generalized-additive-model, gamma-distribution, intercept, marginal-effect

I have two GAMs fitted with a Gamma distribution, with the same model structure with a continuous response variable and one continuous covariate, two categorical covariates, and one random effect:

```
Family: Gamma 
Link function: log 

Formula:
feeding_t ~ s(month, bs = "cc", k = 12) + pop_id_cat + status_cat + s(animals_id, bs = "re")
```

The only difference is the *input dataset*, and **my goal is to compare the two models in the same plot**. But I'm not 100% sure I understand exactly **what is happening in the three different ways of plotting it**.

The summary for the ***first model (Dataset A)*** is:

```
Parametric coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     1.13568    0.04200  27.037  < 2e-16 ***
pop_id_catP2   -0.32086    0.10830  -2.963 0.003066 ** 
pop_id_catP3   -0.21046    0.06111  -3.444 0.000579 ***
pop_id_catP4   -0.12059    0.05760  -2.094 0.036345 *  
pop_id_catP5   -0.16188    0.10134  -1.597 0.110256    
pop_id_catP6   -0.22993    0.05509  -4.173 3.06e-05 ***
pop_id_catP7   -0.19185    0.05620  -3.414 0.000646 ***
pop_id_catP8    0.12648    0.10834   1.167 0.243128    
pop_id_catP9    0.12449    0.06822   1.825 0.068114 .  
status_cata_m  -0.15241    0.04149  -3.673 0.000242 ***
status_catfam  -0.21209    0.04192  -5.059 4.38e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                 edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
s(month)       5.451     10 3.698 1.16e-05 ***
s(animals_id) 52.394     97 1.407  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.0948   Deviance explained = 10.8%
-REML = 6799.6  Scale est. = 0.33249   n = 4334
```

And here's the summary for the ***second model (Dataset B)*** is:

```
Parametric coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     1.10106    0.04263  25.829  < 2e-16 ***
pop_id_catP2   -0.27877    0.10781  -2.586 0.009752 ** 
pop_id_catP3   -0.16630    0.06170  -2.696 0.007054 ** 
pop_id_catP4   -0.10823    0.05811  -1.862 0.062608 .  
pop_id_catP5   -0.15529    0.10309  -1.506 0.132050    
pop_id_catP6   -0.19017    0.05513  -3.450 0.000567 ***
pop_id_catP7   -0.15379    0.05646  -2.724 0.006482 ** 
pop_id_catP8   -0.03964    0.10407  -0.381 0.703308    
pop_id_catP9    0.09500    0.06850   1.387 0.165548    
status_cata_m  -0.16370    0.04185  -3.911 9.33e-05 ***
status_catfam  -0.20772    0.04384  -4.738 2.22e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                 edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(month)       4.983     10 2.773 0.00016 ***
s(animals_id) 50.020     97 1.355 < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.0757   Deviance explained = 8.49%
-REML = 6948.2  Scale est. = 0.3626    n = 4338
```

**(1) Original plot, without transforming the y-axis**

```
comp <- compare_smooths(modelA, modelB)
ik_month_comp <- gratia::draw(comp) 
ik_month_comp_ <- ik_month_comp[[2]] # to get s(month)
```

[image]

**(2) Transforming the y-axis back to the original scale**

```
ci_a <- confint(modelA, parm = "s(month)", type = "confidence") |> 
  mutate(est = exp(est + coef(modelA)[1L]), # [1L] gets the intercept
         lower = exp(lower + coef(modelA)[1L]),
         upper = exp(upper + coef(modelA)[1L]))
    
ci_b <- confint(modelB, parm = "s(month)", type = "confidence") |> 
  mutate(est = exp(est + coef(modelB)[1L]),
         lower = exp(lower + coef(modelB)[1L]),
         upper = exp(upper + coef(modelB)[1L]))
    
ci_a$model <- "Dataset_A"
ci_b$model <- "Dataset_B"
ci <- rbind(ci_a, ci_b)
```

[image]

**(3) Y-axis with predicted values**

```
marginaleffects::plot_predictions(modelA, condition = "month")
```

[image]

---

**Question 1:**

**What does a value on the y-axis mean exactly, in each plot?**
For *plot (1)*, is it correct to say here that the y-axis shows the several "coefficient" values of the covariate month (without the intercept and for the reference categories of the two categorical variables)?
For the other two plots, I'm also not 100% sure if the y-axis reflects absolute values or means...

**Question 2:**

**Is the y-axis of *plot (2)* transformed correctly?**
If so, is it correct to say: "in May the feeding time increases the most, up to a mean (*I'm not sure if it's a mean here?*) of 3.4 days, while the lowest value for feeding time is observed in July-August, with a decrease of ~0.6 days" ?

I'm not sure about this because, when I look at the summary of the response variable, the mean values are ~2 (and this also matches what I see on *plot (3)*):

```
summary(datasetA$feeding_t)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.2908  1.2504  2.0004  2.3640  3.0004 11.2507 

summary(datasetB$feeding_t)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.1468  1.1875  2.0000  2.3075  3.0000 11.2507
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should probably also provide the code used to create "1) Original plot, without transforming the y-axis". These are conditional, marginal effects? Because in the second plot, more has been changed than just the scale of the response variable.

Comment: Plot (1) is basically the outcome of a GAM when plotted (but with the two models and with different aesthetics). I will anyway add the code. Can you please clarify what you mean about the second plot?